# Help with command to find username with less than 8 characters

Tags: grep

I just started taking a linux course and am stuck with my assignment.

I need to find the usernames of logged-in users with usernames of fewer than 8 characters. Here is the command that I have tried but it is not working. Would someone please advise what I may have done incorrectly?

```
who | grep '[a-zA-Z0-9]\{1,7\}'
```

The following command here returns 8 character usernames (I have tested and it works)

```
who | grep '[a-zA-Z0-9]\{8\}'
```

Comment: Hi ahsw. Welcome to unix stackexchange! I'd suggest to read through Section 9.3 of the Base Definitions volume of POSIX.1‐2008, Basic Regular Expressions. If you haven't already.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not restricted to using `grep`, then I would suggest using `awk`, which naturally breaks each line up into whitespace-delimited columns, and then ask for rows in which the first column contains less than eight characters:

```
who | awk 'length($1) < 8 {print $1}'
```

Given output from `who` that looks like this:

```
user1      pts/1        2019-11-24 16:31 (host1.example.com)
user1      pts/2        2019-11-24 16:31 (host1.example.com)
deadbeef   pts/3        2019-11-24 20:39 (host2.example.com)
aperson    pts/4        2019-11-24 20:39 (host3.example.com)
igotroot   pts/5        2019-11-24 20:39 (host4.example.com)
```

The above `awk` command would produce:

```
user1
user1
aperson
```

You can pipe the output of `awk` into `sort -u` to remove duplicates.